# How to split a layout into four equal parts in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16589748/11428585).

But I get `Nested weights are bad for performance`. Is there anyway to solve this or should I continue with this warning?

Comment: Post your current layout file. This is not enough information to go by since there's no indication of what type of container you're using.

Comment: It depends on your layout, you can use `ConstraintLayout`, they have slightly better performance than nested layouts. But unless your layout is really complex and big you can ignore the performance thing.

Comment: use `Relative layout for vertically devided` and inside relative layout use `linear layout with horizontal orientation`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this bunch of xml code below: (I've tested it no warning...)

Here is the main content *xml* file, **test.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:weightSum="2"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

<include
    layout="@layout/test_1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="0dp"/>

<include
    layout="@layout/test_2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="0dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

As I used same xml code for the two nested files **test_1.xml** and **test_2.xml**; I am sharing the common code below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And guess what, I found a **responsive** layout as you want to achieve.
Here is the output:

[image: output]

Answer (score 2):

Here is the layout necessary to solve this with `ConstraintLayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/one"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#333"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/two"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/three"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/two"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#444"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/one"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/four"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/three"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#555"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/one"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/four"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/four"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#666"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/two"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/three"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

However, that performance warning is safe to ignore. Nested weights *are* bad for performance, but this will only be noticeable when you have lots of nested weights on many views all being updated frequently (e.g., flinging a `RecyclerView` where each item uses nested weights).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ConstraintLayout` with guidelines. For example, if you want the layout split into 4 equal parts horizontally, you'd use 3 vertical guidelines, one set at 0.25, one set at 0.50 and one set at 0.75. If you want it split vertically, you'd use the same guideline percents but with horizontal guidelines.

You would then position your views with constraints to the guidelines and the parent.

Comment: A snippet presenting your approach would have been much more useful!