# Converting this LinearLayout to Constraint Layout

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"

    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Is it possible to make this with constraint layout?
[I want to achieve something like this which has been asked in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16589389/android-how-to-split-a-view-in-4-equal-parts) but with constraint layout since using this layout my view is getting cut in smaller screen devices and using weight is bad for performance.